# SQL Server simple find/replace on text string within a table column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Its been quite a while since I've run an SQL query and I need a bit of help.

I have a SQL Server database in which I need to do a string find/replace on text content in column "content" in table named "my_table". I'm getting an "invalid object name" error when I try to execute the SQL:

```
UPDATE dbo.MY_TABLE
  SET CONTENT = REPLACE(CONTENT, 'http://123.123.123.123', 'http://www.mysite.com')
  WHERE CONTENT LIKE '%http://123.123.123.123%';
```

The website's html content is stored inside the "my_table" table in a field labeled "Content". I have thousands of instances of the IP address which need to be updated to reflect the new domain name.

Comment: I'm connected to the database and looking at the table, inserted the SQL above into the query field and clicked "Execute", then I get the error in the bottom window of SQL Manager

Comment: Did you try my suggestion -- running: SELECT * FROM dbo.My_Table?

Comment: Apparently I was in the wrong database. The query works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/451de/1

My guess is that the owner of My_Table isn't dbo?  Can you:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.My_Table
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE dbo.MY_TABLE
SET CONTENT = example.com --Enter your actual website name
WHERE CONTENT LIKE oldexample.com --enter what address you want replace
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the field name. It is a reserved word. Change **content** by **[content]**

Comment: This seems inaccurate based on this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.100%29